# How do I parse this XML from a database field in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this XML that is in a field from a sql query, but I'd like to pull out the EventID from it.

```
<Form>
  <Row LegID="1" EventID="8242323" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26881933" oID="4" />
  <Row LegID="2" EventID="8274278" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27000091" oID="1" />
  <Row LegID="3" EventID="8274189" MarType="HCWEST" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26999824" oID="2" />
  <Row LegID="4" EventID="8243036" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26884162" oID="2" />
  <Row LegID="5" EventID="8246510" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26898727" oID="2" />
  <Row LegID="6" EventID="8301802" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27101445" oID="4" />
  <Row LegID="7" EventID="8305000" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27111681" oID="1" />
  <Row LegID="8" EventID="8299986" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27095255" oID="1" />
</Form>
```

I've tried using the 'Shredding XML' section from [this page](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/), but I'm guessing that doesn't work because my XML is not formed with open and close tags for each item.

Anyone know what the task I'm trying to do is called?

//EDIT//

Awesome I can read it, but I have a follow question.
My select is like this:

```
SELECT LegNumber, X.Col.value('(Row/@EventID)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS 'EventID'
FROM myTable mt
CROSS APPLY mt.MultiLegXML.nodes('/Form') as X(Col)
```

`LegNumber` is an int that corresponds to `LegID` in the XML.
`If LegNumber = 2`, how can I read the EventID from the second row? `(Where LegID = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will help you

```
    declare @xml xml;
    set @xml = '<Form>
      <Row LegID="1" EventID="8242323" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26881933" oID="4" />
      <Row LegID="2" EventID="8274278" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27000091" oID="1" />
      <Row LegID="3" EventID="8274189" MarType="HCWEST" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26999824" oID="2" />
      <Row LegID="4" EventID="8243036" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26884162" oID="2" />
      <Row LegID="5" EventID="8246510" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="26898727" oID="2" />
      <Row LegID="6" EventID="8301802" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27101445" oID="4" />
      <Row LegID="7" EventID="8305000" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27111681" oID="1" />
      <Row LegID="8" EventID="8299986" MarType="WIN" DivType="FIXED" FMid="27095255" oID="1" />
    </Form>';


    select 
          C.value('@EventID', 'bigint') col
    from
         @xml.nodes('Form/Row') as X(C)
```

after Update the Question

```
 select 
          C.value('@EventID', 'bigint') col
    from
         @xml.nodes('Form/Row') as X(C)
         where C.value('@LegID', 'bigint') = 2
```

Comment: thanks tinka that looks a cleaner way of doing it.
I've just now edited my question if you have any more ideas for me :-)
Cheers, Mario

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to return one value from the XML column for each row in the table, you don't need shredding. Use [`sql:column()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx) function to access value in a table column from XQuery :

```
SELECT 
    LegNumber, 
    MultiLegXML.value('(/Form/Row[@LegID=sql:column("LegNumber")]/@EventID)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS 'EventID'
FROM myTable mt
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b51c/1)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
| LegNumber | EventID |
|-----------|---------|
|         2 | 8274278 |
```

Shredding needed in case there may be several `EventID` values to be returned from one XML data, for example :

```
SELECT 
    LegNumber, 
    X.Col.value('@EventID', 'varchar(25)') AS 'EventID'
FROM myTable mt
CROSS APPLY mt.MultiLegXML.nodes('/Form/Row') as X(Col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok stumbled my way through. :-)

```
SELECT *, X.Col.value('(Row/@EventID)[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS 'EventID'
FROM myTable mt
CROSS APPLY mt.MultiLegXML.nodes('/Form') as X(Col)
```