# How to iterate through a given xml input and insert the data in a TempTable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Hi I have the following xml input in a SP.

```
DECLARE @XmlVariable XML = '<portal><patientid>67518</patientid> 
<forms>
<form id="31"  type="C"/>
<form id="44"  type="D"/>
</forms>
</portal>'
```

I have the following inmemory table:

```
DECLARE @TColumns table (
    FormId int,
    FormType varchar(1),
    PatientId int
  )
```

Now, my intention is to:
1.Iterate the xml and insert the values into the  @TColumns table.
2.Read the @TColumns table **row by row** and based on the 3 column values update some existing table;something like
update myexistingtable set status=4 where Formid=31 && Formtype='C' and PatientId=67518.

For item number 1 above, this is what I have done till now, but there is some syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO @TColumns(FormId,FormType,PatientId)
  SELECT 
     XTbl.Cats.value('.', 'int'),
     XTbl.Cats.value('.', 'varchar(1)'),
     XTbl.Cats.value('.', 'int')
  FROM 
     @XmlVariable.nodes('/portal/forms/form/@id') AS XTbl(Cats),
     @XmlVariable.nodes('/portal/forms/form/@type') AS XTbl(Cats),
     @XmlVariable.nodes('/portal/forms/form/@patientid') AS XTbl(Cats)
```

The error I am getting is:*The correlation name 'XTbl' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.*
Need help on this and also on the item number 2 above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071793/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this

```
 SELECT  
   Tbl1.Form.value('@id', 'int'),  
   Tbl1.Form.value('@type', 'varchar(1)'),  
   Tbl2.Portal.value('patientid', 'int')
FROM 
   @XmlVariable.nodes('//form') Tbl1(Form),
   @XmlVariable.nodes('//portal') Tbl2(Portal)
```

Comment: The correlation name 'Tbl' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

Comment: @user2948533 try this change.

Comment: XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *' -this I am getting on the 4 th line,changed it to 'int' from int though.:)

Comment: @user2948533 yeah not sure about that part... you can try `/portal` instead of `//portal` below, or changing the top to `/portal/patientid`  The error suggests there is more than one value for some reason, which does not make sense to me given your sample data.  Is your data actually different?

Comment: you could also try `//patientid` on the bottom and `'.'` on the top.

Comment: Bingo, the last one worked, thanks, i have copied the correct one above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87995/discussion-between-user2948533-and-hogan).

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped.Yes its is based on Hogan's last suggestion.Thank you!

```
INSERT INTO @TColumns(FormId,FormType,PatientId)
 SELECT  
   Tbl1.Form.value('@id', 'int'),  
   Tbl1.Form.value('@type', 'varchar(1)'),  
   Tbl2.Portal.value('.', 'int')
FROM 
   @XmlVariable.nodes('//form') Tbl1(Form),
   @XmlVariable.nodes('//patientid') Tbl2(Portal)
```